# Reference a Window from Frame

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I have a jsp in which charge an iframe which belongs to a different domain. Inside that iframe there is a JSP which navigates to a servlet who navigates to another JSP.

What I want is to make changes in the primary JSP (in which the iframe is loaded) from the iframes second JSP (have to do that way because they are independent web apps).

I tried to window.top, parent, and all reference the Servlet from the JSP loaded, and in other cases have obtained an access denied response.

There any option to do it or would I have to rethink everything?

In summary:

```
....
<br>< div id="xxxx">< /div>
<br>< div id="yyyy">
<br>< iframe src=(other domain)><br>
    Here I load a webpage. it navigates to a servlet and to a second JSP. This is the JSP to do the inner.html in the "xxxx" div 
<br>< /iframe>
<br>< /div>
....
```

Edited:
For more information:

1.- window.top.getElementById("xxxx")... gets an error (does not accept getElementById)
2.- window.top.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; Works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use messages between window frames. The content in your iframe will send a message to parent frame and parent frame has to explicitly receive that message and take action.

Messages are sent using

```
parentWindowObject.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
```

Are received using

```
addEvent(window, "message", function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

That way you can send objects with instructions on what the parent frame should do. Please note that sending JS to be evaluated is not recommended.

---

You can read more about posting/receiving messages between windows here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Excerpt from the page:

> The window.postMessage method safely enables cross-origin communication. Normally, scripts on different pages are allowed to access each other if and only if the pages that executed them are at locations with the same protocol (usually both https), port number (443 being the default for https), and host (modulo document.domain being set by both pages to the same value). window.postMessage provides a controlled mechanism to circumvent this restriction in a way which is secure when properly used.

Comment: I tried, but it response with the access denied again. In the IE9(have to use it) "developers tool" references the Servlet again.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using to send the message? By all account this should be allowed regardless of the domain. Additionally - for IE9 it's apparently better to rely on strings rather than JS objects, so might be safer to stringify it before sending.

Comment: parent.document.postMessage("finihed", receivedURL);
recivedURL is a var with the complete URL passed from the first jsp through all pages. With an alert I can see that is a correct URL.

Comment: The problem is that you're refering to the document of the parent. That's not allowed. Simply go with `parent.postMessage("finihed", receivedURL);`

Comment: Same response. SCRIPT438: the object that not accept  'getElementById' 
MyServlet, Líne 27 Character 4.   It references the **** servlet everytime

Comment: I'd need a bigger context on what you want to achieve to help you further. I understand that your latest error refers to the code `window.top.getElementById("xxxx")` that's now included in original question. That doesn't look right. Assuming you're calling this Javascript from inside the iframe, you can only use limited fields/methods of window.top. window.top.postMessage is allowed, but accessing any DOM elemennts is not.

Comment: No, is the error with the postMessage using it as you said. I'm thinking on doing it with a trick. I'll use the *** window.top.location.href =  receivedURL+'?xxxx=TextToChange' *** to refresh the first JSP at all and loading the value with the TextToChange.once I'd it working I will continue trying to do it better. Thanks

Comment: What does "modulo" mean in "modulo document.domain"!? :)